How to remove locationX and locationY from flow files?
When retrieving a flow file using vscode, is there a way to remove the <locationX> and <locationY> nodes?
These are really annoying, and make the process of identifying differences between flow versions really hard.
I'm hoping this can be included as part of any retrieve process.
e.g.  A basic flow file looks like
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <environments>Default</environments>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>CanvasMode</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>AUTO_LAYOUT_CANVAS</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>OriginBuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processType>Flow</processType>
    <screens>
        <name>test_screen</name>
        <label>test screen</label>
        <locationX>176</locationX>
        <locationY>134</locationY>
        <allowBack>true</allowBack>
        <allowFinish>true</allowFinish>
        <allowPause>true</allowPause>
        <showFooter>true</showFooter>
        <showHeader>true</showHeader>
    </screens>
    <start>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>0</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>test_cpe</targetReference>
        </connector>
    </start>
    <status>Draft</status>
</Flow>

The <locationX>176</locationX> type nodes add no value, and keep changing between versions, but aren't relevant when using AUTO_LAYOUT_CANVAS

These properties are required. What do I do? I do a search/replace, using regular expressions:
Search: <location(\w)>\d+</location$1>
Replace: <location$1>0</location$1>

Pick your favorite number. When you're done with your work, you can then just upload the flow, and then fix it in Salesforce later (especially with auto-layout mode, it'll fix itself).
It's still manual, unfortunately, but manageable in most cases.
